# Graphql Java hello world: Adding a sub-schema to parent schema is failing

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

I am trying to prototype GraphQL Java(https://github.com/andimarek/graphql-java) and starting to build it from the hello world example. I am using GraphiQL to invoke the graphQL service with schema and it is working for schema {hello1} , but not working for the schema {testPojo}. Please find the code which I am running below. Can some one let me know what is the issue with the below code.

```
static GraphQLSchema schema = null;
 /**
  * POJO to be returned for service method 2
  * @author 
  *
  */
 private class TestPojo {
     String id;
     String name;

     TestPojo(String id, String name) {
         this.id = id;
         this.name = name;
     }

     public String getId() {
         return id;
     }

     public void setId(String id) {
         this.id = id;
     }

     public String getName() {
        return name;
     }

     public void setName(String name) {
         this.name = name;
     }
 }

/**
 * service method 1
 * @return
 */
public String greeting1() {
    return "Hello123";
 }

/**
 * service method 2
 * @return
 */
public TestPojo greeting2() {
    return new TestPojo("1","Jack");
}


/**
 * GraphQl endpoint invoked using GraphiQl
 * @param query
 * @return
 */
@RequestMapping("/query")
public Object testGraphQLWithQuery(@RequestParam("query") String query) {
    return new GraphQL(schema).execute(query).getData();
}

// Schema definition for graphQL
static {

    // sub schema to be added to parent  schema
     GraphQLObjectType testPojo = newObject().name("TestPojo").description("This is a test POJO")
            .field(newFieldDefinition().name("id").type(GraphQLString).build())
            .field(newFieldDefinition().name("name").type(GraphQLString).build())
            .build();


    // parent schema
    GraphQLObjectType queryType = newObject().name("helloWorldQuery")
            .field(newFieldDefinition().type(GraphQLString).name("hello1").dataFetcher(new DataFetcher() {

                @Override
                public Object get(DataFetchingEnvironment arg0) {
                    Object a = new GrapgQLSampleController().greeting1();
                    return a;
                }
            }).build())
            .field(newFieldDefinition().type(testPojo).name("testPojo").dataFetcher(new DataFetcher() {

                @Override
                public Object get(DataFetchingEnvironment arg0) {
                    Object a = new GrapgQLSampleController().greeting2();
                    return a;
                }
            }).build())
            .build();

     schema = GraphQLSchema.newSchema().query(queryType).build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested your code and it seems to be working just fine. You'll have to be more specific as to what you see as wrong.

If your question is why the query `{testPojo}` is invalid, then you should have read the error you got: sub-selection is required. You can not select an entire complex object in GraphQL, you have to specify the sub-fields you want, e.g. `{testPojo {id, name}}` is a valid query and works just fine with your schema.